# How to print multiples of a number based on user input in one line using map

Tags: python

I want to print multiples of a number based on user input in one line using map. But the below code is only working for static inputs:

```
print(list(map(lambda n: 12 * n, [i for i in range(1, 11)])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to take the input from user first and then use `map` and `lambda` (one liner)

example:

```
user_input = int(input())
print(list(map(lambda n, : user_input * n, [i for i in range(1, int(input()))])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use can give dynamic input like this:

```
print(list(map(lambda n,:12*n,[i for i in range(1,int(input()))])))
```

or can use it in for loop.

Comment: I was looking for multiples of a Number(input value).Is it possible to give Dynamic inputs in place of 12.So that whenever i give a nbr as input it should give multiples of that number

Comment: Just replace `12` with `input()` in his code snippet.